# Cannot start playback in media application via Google Assistant

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to make my app respond for Google Assistant commands, and actions like: Hey Google - "next", "previous" and "pause" are working well, but the "play" action either starts another application or does nothing.

I am trying to combine different actions to `PlaybackState.ActionSkipToPrevious`, `PlaybackState.ActionPause`, `PlaybackState.ActionPlay`, but nothing seems to help.

I successfully receive callbacks in `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` for `onPause`, but `onPlay` never seems to be called.

The `MediaSession` lives in the `PlaybackService`, which is the foreground service I use for the actual playback.

I setup the mediaSession in the service `OnCreate`

```
void onCreate() 
{
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(ApplicationContext, nameof(PlaybackService));

    var playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        .SetActions(
        PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPlay
            | PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPlayPause
            | PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPause
            | PlaybackStateCompat.ActionStop
            | PlaybackStateCompat.ActionSkipToNext
            | PlaybackStateCompat.ActionSkipToPrevious)
        .Build();
mediaSession.SetPlaybackState(playbackState);

    var mediaSessionCallback = new MusicIntentReceiver.MediaSessionCallback();
    mediaSession.SetCallback(mediaSessionCallback);
...
```

But also react to the player state changes and reset the playback state

```
stateBuilder.SetActions(
    PlaybackState.ActionSkipToPrevious
    | (!IsPlaying ? PlaybackState.ActionPause : PlaybackState.ActionPlay)
    | PlaybackState.ActionSkipToNext);

mediaSession.SetPlaybackState(stateBuilder.Build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it often happens, the issue was found after posting the question.

The only reason why the "Play" was not working, is because I've deactivated the `mediaPlayer` on playback idle.

Don't do that if you're actively using the media session.

`mediaSession.Active = false`